# Java Hashmap set one element update all elements

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following hashmap

```
Map<String, List<KmsRealesBeanAgrupado> > listadoAgrupado = new HashMap<String , List<KmsRealesBeanAgrupado> >();
```

I have a loop for update each hashmap element, but when I update one hashmap element by index, all elements with this index are update

This is the code

```
  for (Map.Entry<String,List<KmsRealesBeanAgrupado>> elemento1 : listadoAgrupado.entrySet()){  
                listado2 = elemento1.getValue();
                String clave = elemento1.getKey();
                for (KmsRealesBeanAgrupado  elemento : listado2){

                    listaKms = elemento.getListado();
                    listaKms = anadirTotales(listaKms,vista);
                    listadoAgrupado.get(clave).get(j).setListado(listaKms);
                    //elemento.setListado(listaKms);

                    //listado2.get(j).setListado(elemento.getListado());
                }
                j++;
```

When I execute

```
listadoAgrupado.get(clave).get(j).setListado(listaKms);
```

all elements with index j in the hashmap are update.

These are the screen

[image]

Following element hashmap

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you did not put the same list into the HashMap under different keys? If so, there is really only one copy, and if you update it through one key, it will show up under all other keys as well.

Comment: Your screenshots show different lists, I suspect that keys are different to. What you want to achieve? Update all elements in all lists?

Comment: But you are iterating over whole map and doing update, so why it's a surprise?

Comment: My Hashmap has different keys. Each different key has as value a list. I want update the list for each key

Comment: I don't know how I can update each list for each key

Comment: Your `KmsRealesBeanAgrupado` contains same list in `listado` field.

Comment: Each key in the map has some listado fields

Comment: Could it be that every `listadoAgrupado.get(clave).get(j)` is the same object, the same list; just filled with other elements? That is a beginner's error. In general one should create a new value for ever map entry: `listadoAgrupado.put(clave), new ArrayList<>(otherList));

Answer (score 0):

Strange code. I don't have a clear answer but just some remarks on your code. Hope it helps you to understand where your problem is.

`listadoAgrupado.get(clave)` is the same as `listado2`.
In your inner `for` loop you walk throug all elements of `listado2`, you do some calculation and then you store the updated `listaKms` in the KmsRealesBeanAgrupado element at position `j` of that same list `listado2`. So you always update the same KmsRealesBeanAgrupado instance (at index j). `listadoAgrupado.get(clave).get(j)` always refers to the same list element. Is this really what you want ?

We don't have the code of `anadirTotales`. Does this returns a different list or does it update the input parameter list. In case it just updates, you have to set it afterwards.

`j`is increased in the outer loop. When iterating over de map, in the first iteration all calculations will be put in the first element of the `listadoAgrupado.get("key1")` list.
The second iteration all calculations will be put in the second element of the `listadoAgrupado.get("key2")` list.

Comment: I have a hasmap with some keys. Each key has some elements. Each element has a list. I want to get for each key their lists, do calculations for each list and  update the lists for each key. listadoAgrupado.get(clave).get(j), the index j is the index of list element of each key. My problem is that when I get listadoAgrupado.get(clave).get(j), all elements with index j in every key is update

Comment: Then you should look at how your map is filled. If your `KmsRealesBeanAgrupado`instances are different but they all have a reference to the same listado List instance, you will have the behaviour you describe. (as already sdtressed by @Thilo)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the whole list here:

```
listaKms = anadirTotales(listaKms,vista)
```

as the `List<KmsRealesBeanAgrupado>>` is a refernce type so when you are setting the value in the reference type it updates the value in the hashmap.

Try using this:

```
    for (Map.Entry<String,List<KmsRealesBeanAgrupado>> elemento1 : listadoAgrupado.entrySet()){  
            listado2 = elemento1.getValue();
            String clave = elemento1.getKey();
            for (KmsRealesBeanAgrupado  elemento : listado2){

                listaKms = elemento.getListado();
                //listaKms = anadirTotales(listaKms,vista);
                //don't manipulate listaKms otherwise it will get reflected in hashmap
                  List<KmsRealesBeanAgrupado>> lap = anadirTotales(listaKms,vista);
                listadoAgrupado.get(clave).get(j).setListado(lap);
                //elemento.setListado(listaKms);

                //listado2.get(j).setListado(elemento.getListado());
            }
            j++;
```